# Having trouble importing nltk.etree.elementtree

Tags: python, xml, nlp, nltk, importerror

I'm following along with Natural Language Processing with Python. when i run

```
from nltk.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

etree was removed from ntlk back in 2012 (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/80):

> StevenBird1 said, at 2011-03-31T05:10:58.000Z:
>
> Yes -- etree has been in the standard library since version 2.5. It
>   was just a temporary measure to include etree for the benefit of
>   people using 2.4.

This should work for you:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
```